# LaTeX does not find the command although PATH is specified

Tags: mactex, paths, macos, bash

LaTeX fails to pass the command to bash even though PATH is specified. For example, I am trying to invoke `texcount`, which is in directory `/Library/TeX/textbin`. When I check `echo $PATH`, the output I get is follows:

`/Library/TeX/textbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Even when I run `texcount` from MacOS terminal, it works fine. However, it does not work when I have my command defined as:

`\NewDocumentCommand\wordcount{s}{\immediate\write18{texcount}}`

Instead if I specify full PATH as `\NewDocumentCommand\wordcount{s}{\immediate\write18{/Library/TeX/textbin/texcount}}`, it works fine.

Comment: `/Library/TeX/textbin` would seem to be a typo. Try `/Library/TeX/texbin` instead. For sure, the MacTeX installation on my system has lots of files (including `texcount`) under `/Libary/TeX/texbin`...

Comment: I do not know why, my MacTeX installation has two folders `/Library/TeX/texbin` and `/Library/TeX/textbin`. They both are equivalent and I tried with both options in my PATH. No luck though.

Comment: If there are two similar-looking folder names, chances are that something went badly wrong during the installation of MacTeX. (You're on MacTeX2018, right?) I would blow away both `/Library/TeX/texbin` and `/Library/TeX/textbin` and reinstall MacTeX from scratch. Do also make sure that, from now on, the first entry in the path variable points to `/Library/TeX/texbin` (not textbin).

Comment: Yes, I am using MacTeX2018. I have installed it very recently. Anyhow, I found out my problem. I am using TeXStudio for editing files and apparently, I need to update the PATH in `TeXStudio preferences -> Build -> Additional Search PATH` to my new MacTeX 2018 directory. Since, I had deleted the old directories, the old PATH which is in TeXStudio preferences was not able to find the command.

Comment: have you used the `--shell-escape` option to allow calling the shell?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, I have `--shell-escape` option enabled.

Comment: try `\write18{echo $PATH}` and see what path is being set in the tex enviornment